# 4.5 years supposed to be 4 years and 178, How I can do that In C++

Tags: c++

Title is just an example.

I am making an app in C++ and need to show the time required to achieve a given point. If I go to alpha centauri at light speed, I would reach it after 4 years 133 days, but the output is `4.367 years`.

How can I convert `4.367 years` to `4 years 133 days`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double percent = 0;
    double speed_light = 1 ; // Light/Years
    double alpha_centauri = 4.367;
    double alpha_centauri_days = 1595.0467;

    cout << "Please inter the percentage of light speed the spaceship is flying with:\n";
    cin >> percent;

    double per_speed = percent * speed_light /100;
    double year_time = alpha_centauri / per_speed ;
    int days_time = alpha_centauri_days / per_speed ;

    cout <<"The time required to reach alpha centauri at "<< percent
    << " percent of light speed is: \n"<< year_time << " years!\t" << days_time<< " days!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include your inputs? i.e. what do you enter as `percent` where you expect "light speed is 4 years! 178 days!"? What does it say currently? "4.5 years! 0 days!"?

Comment: Please note that if you enter the "percentage of light speed", the velocity would be `percent * speed_light`.

Comment: Without giving away too much, how would you convert 1.25 hours into 1 hour 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the simplifying assumption that one year equals 365 days. Then divide by 365 to get the years, and modulo 365 to get the days left over.

```
int days_time = alpha_centauri_days / per_speed ;

cout <<"The time required to reach alpha centauri at "<< percent
<< " percent of light speed is: \n"<< days_time/365 << " years!\t" << days_time%365 << " days!\n";
```

You don't need the `year_time` variable.

Answer (score 0):

`x-floor(x)` gives you fractional part.

`(x-floor(x))*365.25` gives days left after years are removed from `x`.